# paramiko connect() error: wanted object (0x06), got 0x30

Tags: python, paramiko

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(NODE, username=SETTINGS['username'], password=SETTINGS['password'])
```

Could someone tell me what this error means when I try to ssh with paramiko?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n
  File "/path/stats.py", line 104, in connect\r\n
    ssh.connect(NODE, username=SETTINGS['username'], password=SETTINGS['password'])\r\n
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paramiko-1.16.0-py3.2.egg/paramiko/client.py", line 367, in connect\r\n
    look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host)\r\n
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paramiko-1.16.0-py3.2.egg/paramiko/client.py", line 558, in _auth\r\n
    key = pkey_class.from_private_key_file(filename, password)\r\n
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paramiko-1.16.0-py3.2.egg/paramiko/pkey.py", line 184, in from_private_key_file\r\n
    key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)\r\n
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paramiko-1.16.0-py3.2.egg/paramiko/ecdsakey.py", line 49, in __init__\r\n
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)\r\n
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paramiko-1.16.0-py3.2.egg/paramiko/ecdsakey.py", line 146, in _from_private_key_file\r\n
    self._decode_key(data)\r\n
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paramiko-1.16.0-py3.2.egg/paramiko/ecdsakey.py", line 161, in _decode_key\r\n
    key = SigningKey.from_der(data)\r\n
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/site-packages/ecdsa-0.13-py3.2.egg/ecdsa/keys.py", line 178, in from_der\r\n
    curve_oid, empty = der.remove_object(curve_oid_str)\r\n
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/site-packages/ecdsa-0.13-py3.2.egg/ecdsa/der.py", line 82, in remove_object\r\n
    raise UnexpectedDER("wanted object (0x06), got 0x%02x" % n)\r\n
ecdsa.der.UnexpectedDER: wanted object (0x06), got 0x30\r\n
```

Comment: 0x06 object: Acknowledge. 0x30 object: 0     What/where/how it goes wrong I do not know though..

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure why this was happening, I was able to work around it by passing `look_for_keys=False` to `connect()`.